# How to Store Select list data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have several drop down lists (Select HTML elements) that need to be populated in the admin page. I wanted to know what is the recommend way to store in MongoDB?

Should I store each data (e.g. company list, country list) in a single document called for example Globals, and retrieve those by querying that single document?

Comment: are you using mongoose?

Comment: No, developing in ASP.NET C# Server side and jQuery on client side.

Comment: The ideal way would be to have all the exhaustive lists in separate collections and have references from other documents to it. So that data is not duplicated. But you need to do multiple queries each time to get the data from the reference. Mongoose has a neat option called `populate` which offers this and makes using references a dream. Check if your driver has an equivalent feature. Without it cross referencing is a pain.

Comment: @ma08 I just need the lists for the admin and front for searching for the user to choose from, not to embed the list inside other documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will need the lists for dropdowns only, just store the lists in a single document as arrays. The collection will contain only this document so you can use `findOne({})`. But if you need to search for the lists(autocomplete) the ideal design will be a lot more different.